# Deploy to Google App Engine Flex environment from Google Cloud Build using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

I have a Google App Engine Flex project, which contains the following files:

- `app.yaml` - to define the App Engine Flex environment
- `Dockerfile` - based on a Google App Engine container with some additions
- `cloudbuild.yaml`

**cloudbuild.yaml** content:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '--tag=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<projectname>', '.']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy']
timeout: '1600s'
images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<projectname>']
```

This is based on the docs at:
https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/build-test-deploy-artifacts#deploying_artifacts

I'm getting the following error on the `app deploy` command:

> A custom runtime must have exactly one of [Dockerfile] and [cloudbuild.yaml] in the source directory

Without `cloudbuild.yaml` it doesn't know to try and deploy the app, without the `Dockerfile` it doesn't know what is in it, so how do I specify the same workflow with only one of these?

Comment: change the location of cloudbuild.yaml

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into the same issue working on a Django project on a flex app engine with  a custom docker file. I moved all project files except couldbuild.yaml into a subfolder and in the cloudbuild.yaml specified the subfolder like so

```
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "<subfolder>/app.yaml"]
timeout: "1600s"
```

That worked for me.

(see also [does appengine cloudbuild.yaml requires a custom runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555496/does-appengine-cloudbuild-yaml-requires-a-custom-runtime))

Comment: It worked for me. I had a problem of expiration every time I wanted to build using cloudbuild. After one day of trying, I've just moved every file in the project except the .cloudbuild.yaml and .git folder to some subfolder. And it worked fine !

Answer (score 4):

My approach was the other way around. Put the cloudbuild configuration in a subfolder and use the `--config="<folder>`

Comment: I like this solution since you don't need to change other file structure :)
you can set --config for github integration etc. at https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/triggers?authuser=0&supportedpurview=project