# does appengine cloudbuild.yaml requires a custom runtime?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

Build errors out with below output (Using a Rails app)

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) There is a cloudbuild.yaml in the current directory, and the runtime field in /workspace/app.yaml is currently set to [runtime: ruby]. To use your cloudbuild.yaml to build a custom runtime, set the runtime field to [runtime: custom]. To continue using the [ruby] runtime, please remove the cloudbuild.yaml from this directory.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloudbuild.yaml should work with App Engine Flexible without the need to use a custom runtime. As detailed in the error message, you cannot have the app.yaml and the cloudbuild.yaml in the same directory if you are deploying in a non-custom runtime, to remedy the situation, follow these steps:

1. Move the app.yaml and other ruby files into a subdirectory (use your original app.yaml, no need to use custom runtime)
2. Under your cloudbuild.yaml steps, modify the argument for app deploy by adding a third one specifying the app.yaml path.

Below is an example:

==================FROM:

```
steps: 
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud' 
args: ['app', 'deploy'] 
timeout: '1600s'
```

===================TO:

```
steps: 
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud' 
args: ['app', 'deploy', '[SUBDIRECTORY/app.yaml]'] 
timeout: '1600s'
```

Comment: This is an old question, but @David do you then need to make your app.yaml "directory aware" ? I'm getting odd errors in my deploy step that package.json is not found

Comment: I've had _some_ success with using /bin/bash to copy app.yaml from a sub-directory to the main directory during the cloud build process.

Comment: @stevecowling My answer may help you out.

Answer (score 8):

One way to deal with this is to change the name of the `cloudbuild.yaml` file to say `cloud_build.yaml` (you can also just move the file) and then go to your triggers in Cloud Build:

[image]

And change it from `Autodetected` to choosing your `Cloud Build configuration file` manually:

[image]

See this [Github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/397) for some more information

Comment: its working but version is not showing. like there is nothing deployed