# Google Cloud Build - build.yaml & app.yaml in a sub directory not building correct source

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-build, app.yaml

I'm having trouble setting up my yaml files for google app engine. The configuration works correctly when my app.yaml file is in the root of the project but if it is within a subdirectory it does not build the correct source. I suspect I need to set the `dir:` option in the build config, but I have tried multiple variations and I can't get it to work.

Working file structure, deployed app is ~3mb in size.

```
src
deployment
└── staging
    └── build.yaml
app.staging.yaml


# build.yaml
steps:
- name: node:12
  entrypoint: yarn
- name: node:12
  entrypoint: yarn
  args: ['build']
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "app.staging.yaml"]
timeout: "1800s"
```

Not working file structure, deployed app is ~1kb in size.

```
src
deployment
└── staging
    └── build.yaml
    └── app.yaml


# build.yaml
steps:
- name: node:12
  entrypoint: yarn
- name: node:12
  entrypoint: yarn
  args: ['build']
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "deployment/staging/app.yaml"]
timeout: "1800s"
```

In both scenarios I am kicking off the deployment with:
`gcloud builds submit --config deployment/staging/build.yaml`

What should my `dir:` be set to in the build.yaml steps so that the build step knows to build from root? Is there any way to debug this locally without having to upload the source every time?

Thanks!
A

Comment: What's your error trace?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, I saw that SO issue but I couldn't work out what the correct dir: value should be.

In both cases the app deploy successfully but in the second case when accessing the url I receive a 500 error and the deployed code is only ~600 bytes which suggests to me it's deployed an empty folder or something like that.

This leads me to believe I need to specify the source for the build step, but if I am running the cloudbuild from within a subfolder how do I escape up the folder tree, e.g. ../../ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot have the app.yaml and the cloudbuild.yaml in the same directory if you are deploying in a non-custom runtime. Please see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555496/does-appengine-cloudbuild-yaml-requires-a-custom-runtime#answer-52558814)

Comment: Interesting, I don't any errors though when deploying.

Answer (score 1):

I believe by default cloud build expects the app.yaml file to be in the uppermost directory. I'm not sure if it's possible to change this in the cloud build settings.